# Android Development - allow any host to connect to MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, mamp, host

I'm trying to connect remotely to my MySQL server from a basic android app.
I can connect to server just fine using 'localhost', but I also want any host to connect to the server (for simplicity, for now).

I have the two following users in my phpMyAdmin:

```
User    Host       Password  Global privileges  Grant
root    %           Yes      ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes    
root    localhost   Yes      ALL PRIVILEGES      Yes
```

my variables to connect to the database are:

```
/*
* All database connection variables
*/

define('DB_USER', "root"); // db user
define('DB_PASSWORD', "myPass"); // db password (mention your db password here)
define('DB_DATABASE', "mainData"); // database name
define('DB_SERVER', ''); // db server
?>
```

i have also edited the my.cnf, i am using MAMP PRO. I modified this line:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

I have also unchecked the "Allow local access only" option in MAMP PRO.

I restarted the server, and i still can't connect from a host that is not localhost. I have the android application installed on several phones, but i am only able to connect to the database on localhost.

I have looked around the forums and couldnt find a different solution. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your server has a firewall blocking outside connections?

Answer (score 1):

How about making a call to PHP and having that script access MySQL as opposed to clients hitting port 3306?

Comment: this is exactly what i am doing, I have checked that port 3306 is open and listening, still no success.

Comment: i am suggesting that the Android users connect to your web server on port 80 to send requests. the server then has php scripts that talk to localhost:3306, get the data, encode, and send back on port 80 (or 443). I don't think we are saying the same thing. Your Android phones out there should not be talking to 3306 over the air.

Comment: to be clear, only your webservers (PHP,Python,whatever) sitting on port 80/443 are in the DMZ and reachable by the phones. Your MySql/MSSQL servers are protected behind the firewall and not reachable from the internet. If you have one server that is both webserver and database server the same still applies. The database ports are closed to the outside world.

Comment: I am currently using a JSON parser to send a request to the web server by making an HttpRequest using port 8888, the web server (PHP), then interacts with the MySql DB by using localhost:3306 . should i switch to port 80?

Comment: I would because you can bank on 80 and 443 to be open from internet cafes and schools and public libraries etc where many ports going out are shut down.

Answer (score 1):

the easiest check possible whether the firewall is blocking connections to db server would be. to use a workstation and try to use telnet to the port 3306. this would atleast tell you where the problem exists, in the app or the network.

one more thing would be good to check on the MAMP Server is whether port is actually opened on 0.0.0.0:3306 or 127.0.0.1:3306

try `netstat -an | find "3306"`

Comment: netstat gives me: tcp4       0      0  *.3306                 *.*                    LISTEN

Comment: did you try to do telnet ipaddress 3306 ?

Comment: telnet return:
Connected to new-host.home.
Escape character is '^]'.
J
5.5.25W'Wbg`*?2J]tR|<Use~jmysql_native_passwordConnection closed by foreign host.

Comment: MySQL server is working fine and seems no issue with the network. most likely the problem is occurring in the android code. in your android code where you are connecting, can you put a try catch and then log the exception (if there is any) and paste the logcat logs here. if possible provide some of your android code here.

Comment: one more thing to add, have u grated your db access to the remote ip (ip of the android). since the phone ip can change every time it is connected to 3G or Wifi (unless static ip is set). you might want to give ur db access to remote ip, mysql> GRANT ALL ON foo.* TO dbuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

Comment: yes i did:  <br/> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';

Comment: it seems here that you are calling a php file on the webserver, which is inturn connecting to the db. not the android app directly connecting. well in that case you might want to check exact error message on the webserver (apache) logs or in your php code put a try catch and log the message in the webpage.

Comment: seems the issue is with permission within mysql. initial error in the error_log suggest problem with the root user unable to connect to db. last few sets of error suggest the hostname provided is not allowed to connect. may be you try to create a user such as below **`mysql> GRANT ALL ON DB_NAME.* TO android@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';`** try the username 'android' and password as 'password' in your db.config file.

Comment: it seems that the error log was an old log, i cleared the log and started the server again. no errors. however i still can't connect to the server. I will post a logcat of the errors on my phone from the moment the app is started to the point where the app crashed. The app is stuck at a loading screen where it tries to connect to the server initially.

Comment: should my database connection variables be different?

Comment: what do you mean by database variables be different? I looked at the log from your phone, there doesnt seem to be any exception/error which can tell us what is going wrong.

Comment: I decided to scratch the idea of running my own server, I ended up getting a web host instead, everything runs good now. I appreciate your help @Dilberted. Thank you very much!